# Django two table relationship, but not both

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table called Post. A post can have 2 videos or 2 images, but not both. The table schema for a post looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    header          = models.CharField()
    created_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have two tables that look similar to each other:

```
class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img  = models.ImageField()


class PostVideo(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField()
```

How do I create and enforce the relationship where a post can have maximum and minimum of 2 images or 2 videos, but it can't have both videos and images at the same time? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: when save 2 images, you can check if this user has videos in PostVideo model or vice versa.

Comment: Or you can create only one model with OneToOneField to Post and in this model create arrayfield which will save two elements.

Comment: @sandeep which save method would I write this code in? The post save method or the 2 other models?

Comment: If you are using 1st method, check before saving image/video. But I think you should use 2nd method. then you won't have to check anything as it is OneToOneField and you can save two elements in ArrayField (either video or image)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can write a `Mixin` class like this:

```
class PostMixin(object):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(self, 'img') and self.post.images.exists():
             raise ValidationError('Already have an image')
        elif hasattr(self, 'video') and self.post.videos.exists():
             raise ValidationError('Already have a video')
        super(PostMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class PostImage(PostMixin, models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
    img  = models.ImageField()


class PostVideo(PostMixin, models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="videos")
    video = models.FileField()
```

But rather than handling them in model, you should handle them in forms or serializers(if you are using DRF).

Comment: I really like this solution, however, how would I implement something like this in a serializer? Shouldn't the model restrict this from happening in the serializer?

Comment: It will restrict it, but the code isn't clean in my opinion. IMHO Validation should be done in serializer because it is there for that purpose.

Comment: Very sorry, but how would you write a validator like this for a serializer?

Comment: Hi, I actually made a new question with more in depth logic of what I'm trying to create, could you please take a look? I added my serializer code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59406141/django-creating-constraints-on-serializers

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to add a `pre_save` signal for both `PostImage` and `PostVideo` and check your conditions there:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=PostVideo)
@receiver(pre_save, sender=PostImage)
def post_validator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    images_count = instance.post.postimage_set.count()
    videos_count = instance.post.postvideo_set.count()
    if not (<your conditions met>):
        raise ValidationError('Conditions not met!')
```