# Django Creating constraints on serializers

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to extend Django's Poll app. Each poll will have 2 choices and either an image for each choice or a color for each choice, but not both. My models look like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
      question = models.CharField()
      created_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Choice(models.Model):
      question    = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      choice      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
      vote_count  = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class ChoiceImage(models.Model):
    choice = models.OneToOneField(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img    = models.ImageField()

class ChoiceColor(models.Model):
    choice = models.OneToOneField(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color  = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

I have a View that looks like this:

```
    class CreateQuestionView(CreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = CreateQuestionSerializer
```

With the following serializers:

```
class ChoiceImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChoiceImage
        fields = ('image',)

class ChoiceColorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChoiceColor
        fields = ('color',)

class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choice_image = ChoiceImageSerializer(many=False)
    choice_color = ChoiceColorSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('choice', 'choice_image', 'choice_color')


class CreateQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question', 'choices')
```

How do I create this constraint on my serializers? Also Am I designing this efficiently or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to define the validation on the model level? It would be rather strange that a certain value is invalid if passed through the serializers, but not through a form for example.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hmm, you're right, however, I'm very confused as with my design...am I designing what I want to achieve correctly or is there a more efficient way to create this rather than having nested relationships?